# Inheritance and Polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

There's a simple question, **What will the program print to the console?**

I never thought that I could be wrong as much as I was with this piece of code. It behaved the other way around of what my logic expected from it.

If someone could please enlighten the reason for each line printed I would be really appreciate that.

And also, what is the meaning of instantiating a new Circle and casting it to a Shape? why is it treated also as an Ellipse?

Thank you so much

**EDIT:**
I was asked to specify what was I expecting the output to be.
So:

1. creating a Circle and casting it to a Shape, I was thinking that only the Shape C'tor will be executed, as it's a Shape.
2. What's the point of calling **super()** if it's done automatically? the Ellipse C'tor executed the code in the Shape C'tor.
3. Why does x1.Draw() which is casted to Shape is executing the code of Ellipse's Draw()? as you can see both x1,x2 printed the same message.

Hope I was more clear, thank you.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Shape
    {
        public Shape()
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("SHAPE CTOR");
        }

        public virtual void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shape.Draw()");
        }
    }

    class Ellipse : Shape
    {
        public Ellipse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ELLIPSE CTOR");
        }

        public sealed override void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ELLIPSE.Draw()");
        }
    }

    class Circle : Ellipse
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Shape x1 = (Shape)new Circle();
            Ellipse x2 = (Ellipse)new Circle();
            Circle x3 = new Circle();
            x1.Draw();
            x2.Draw();
            x3.Draw();
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CIRCLE DRAW");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SHAPE CTOR
ELLIPSE CTOR
SHAPE CTOR
ELLIPSE CTOR
SHAPE CTOR
ELLIPSE CTOR
ELLIPSE.Draw()
ELLIPSE.Draw()
CIRCLE DRAW
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly did you expect, and why?

Comment: This is normal behavior, and unless you tell us what you expected, as @O.R.Mapper has stated, we won't know what to you're failing to understand.  Otherwise, this is going to turn into a big lesson on polymorphism and inheritance... and there are plenty of resources online for that.

Comment: I guess @johni is missing that Circle has no ctor and that is why it is printing shap there.

Comment: I have edited my post for your convenience, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @peer: `Circle` has a ctor (it is invoked in each of the first three lines of `Main()`), and even if it somehow had none, this could not possibly be related to the polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: Suggestion: latest "expert" thinking on the subject is that inheritance is bad. So in answer to your question: don't worry about what will be printed. Forget inheritance and focus on composition, pure functions, dependency injection and test-driven-development as the key things for you to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> creating a Circle and casting it to a Shape, I was thinking that only the Shape C'tor will be executed, as it's a Shape.

When you write `new Circle()`, it creates an instance of `Circle`, so it calls the constructor of `Circle`. The cast is done afterwards. Actually, in this case the cast is redundant, because a `Circle` already *is* a `Shape`. You're just assigning the instance of `Circle` to a variable of type `Shape`; this way the compiler doesn't know the actual concrete type of the variable. The `Circle` instance is not actually converted to anything else.

> What's the point of calling super() if it's done automatically? the Ellipse C'tor executed the code in the Shape C'tor.

I assume you mean `base()` rather than `super()`; but anyway, you're not calling it, the compiler does it for you automatically. The constructor of a derived class must always call a constructor of the base class to initialize the state of the base class. In the case of the default constructor, you don't need to do it explicitly because the compiler does it for you.

> Why does x1.Draw() which is casted to Shape is executing the code of Ellipse's Draw()? as you can see both x1,x2 printed the same message.

That's the whole point of polymorphism. At runtime, the method that is executed depends on the actual concrete type of the object. Since `Ellipse` overrides the `Shape.Draw` method, it is the `Ellipse` implementation that is executed for an instance of `Ellipse`.

Note that in the `Circle` class, you didn't use the `override` keyword on the `Draw` method; this means that `Circle.Draw` does *not* override `Shape.Draw`, it's just an unrelated method that just happens to have the same name. It will not participate in polymorphism, it will only be called if you call it through a variable of type `Circle`.

Answer (score 0):

1. For every type in the inheritance tree (at least) one constructor must be called. Hence you see every constructor print in your case.
2. To redirect to a specific (overload of an) constructor.
3. Since the last implementation on the class is called. Even if the object is casted, it will still call the last type's method (unless you break inheritance through `new`).

Answer (score -1):

1. > creating a Circle and casting it to a Shape, I was thinking that only
   >   the Shape C'tor will be executed, as it's a Shape.

   As you are saying: You are creating a `Circle` and casting it to a `Shape`. The constructor will only be called when you are creating an instance of an object. Therefor you are simply calling the constructor of `Circle`. The process of casting is not calling any constructors.
2. You always need to call the base constructor with `: base()`. When there is a parameter less base constructor the compiler will add the `: base()` for you (Because its clear). You can use `base()` to call a specific base constructor which might not be the parameterless one.
3. The `Draw()` method you have there in your `Circle` class is only known by the compiler when you have a `Circle` instance. In you case you have got a `Ellipse` and a `Shape` which don't know about the custom `Draw`method and are therefor calling the overridden `Draw` method from `Ellipse`

Comment: "the object will be instantiated and will then be converted into a Shape" - I fear this is misleading. The object will not be converted, or changed, at all.